# Clang doesn't know PTRDIFF_MAX?

Tags: c++, clang

I'm upgrading our build machine (from Windows Server 2008 to Windows 10) and have a build that ran fine on the old machine (using Visual Studio). I had some problems getting it to run with VS Build Tools (I'm trying to avoid needing a VS license) on the new machine, so I'm porting it to use Clang.

The build uses Flatbuffers, which I have upgraded from 1.4.0 to 1.12.0. I'm getting the following error during the build:

```
[2/70] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\polyphemus.dir\hardwareconfig.cpp.obj

FAILED: CMakeFiles/polyphemus.dir/hardwareconfig.cpp.obj 

C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\BUILDT~1\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin\clang-cl.exe  /nologo -TP  -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\nanomsg\include\nanomsg" -I. -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\FlatBuffers\include" -IE:\JenkinsMIDEBLD\workspace\btaylor-new_build_node_CYC-268_2\polyphemus\include /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /GR /EHsc /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -MDd /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\polyphemus.dir\hardwareconfig.cpp.obj /FdCMakeFiles\polyphemus.dir\polyphemus.pdb -c E:\JenkinsMIDEBLD\workspace\btaylor-new_build_node_CYC-268_2\polyphemus\hardwareconfig.cpp

In file included from E:\JenkinsMIDEBLD\workspace\btaylor-new_build_node_CYC-268_2\polyphemus\hardwareconfig.cpp:3:
In file included from .\hardwareconfig_generated.h:7:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\FlatBuffers\include\flatbuffers/flatbuffers.h:20:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\FlatBuffers\include\flatbuffers/base.h:45:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\algorithm(37,63): error: use of undeclared identifier 'PTRDIFF_MAX'
    return static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(_Min_value(static_cast<_CT>(PTRDIFF_MAX), static_cast<_CT>(_Value)));
```

Not having PTRDIFF_MAX defined is really rather odd, and suggests that Flatbuffers should have done `#include <cstdint>` in its files, but hasn't. This seems like something that would cause tests to fail, so I can't believe that's an undiagnosed bug. Sure enough, if I add `#include <cstdint>` to my files, they start building. This really doesn't seem like the correct solution though - I can't believe that Flatbuffers has an undocumented dependency that you have to do that import yourself, which suggests I'm doing something wrong. Does anyone know what, please?

EDIT: Explicitly turning on C++17 in cmake (and from there in clang) results in the same error in a different place that doesn't involve flatbuffers:

```
In file included from E:\JenkinsMIDEBLD\workspace\btaylor-new_build_node_CYC-268_2\polyphemus\complexseries.cpp:2:
In file included from E:\JenkinsMIDEBLD\workspace\btaylor-new_build_node_CYC-268_2\polyphemus\include\polyphemus/complexseries.h:4:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\complex:12:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\sstream:11:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\istream:11:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\ostream:11:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\ios:11:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\xlocnum:16:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\streambuf:11:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\xiosbase:12:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\system_error:14:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\stdexcept:12:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\xstring(1258,47): error: use of undeclared identifier 'PTRDIFF_MAX'
        return _Min_value(static_cast<size_t>(PTRDIFF_MAX), static_cast<size_t>(-1) / sizeof(_Elem));
```

That's in a file where I'd done my own #include of , so I guess that's a red herring (and also not a fix :-/ ).

Comment: Note that the actual error comes from the header `<algorithm>`, signalling that there's something more fundamentally wrong with your build setup, rather than the FlatBuffers headers.

Comment: Could it be that C++11 is somehow not enabled?

Comment: I noticed that, but that being wrong seemed even less likely than Flatbuffers being wrong...

Comment: On C++11... maaaybe? I think our previous build didn't use C++11 because the old version of the Visual Studio compiler we were using didn't support it. I can't see anywhere explicitly switching it off though.

Comment: Well that's weird. Explicitly turning on C++17 in cmake (and from there in clang) results in the same error in a different place. This time in one of the files I'd included cstdint myself. No flatbuffers, this time it's all in Visual Studio.

Comment: @BenTaylor What do you mean by "*avoid needing a VS license*"? The starter edition of Visual Studio has been free for some years.

Comment: Sadly, my use case doesn't meet the licensing conditions to use VS Community Edition!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that I had in my include path a version of stdint.h that specifies it was for use "only with Microsoft Visual C++ compilers!". Unsurprisingly, it turns out it doesn't work with Clang. You'd expect it to either fail catastrophically or else just work anyway (it does define PTRDIFF_MAX), but I guess it just causes Clang to be very very confused.

Anyway, if I remove it from my include path, things start working.

Comment: Just to expand on this, the version I had was from https://code.google.com/archive/p/msinttypes/ - the old VS compiler I was using before didn't support C99, so I needed that header to let SWIG work with Python 3. Obviously now I've upgraded the compiler, I don't need the extra header file!